# Android activity launched with parameter is launched into caller's task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parameters, manifest

My Android audio app can be started with parameter using intents. This works so far, but the calling app (e.g. ES explorer) disappears and is not usable until my app is closed. I want my app to be started independently from the starting app. Is this controlled by the starting app or can I adjust anything to make my activity standalone? Thanks!

My Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Activityname"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/wav" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Settingsname" />
    <service android:name=".Servicename" />
</application>
```

My (working) Intent receivement in the activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String paramUrl = intent.getDataString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delcare your `Activityname` activity to have `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the manifest. Then, if another app launches your `Activityname` via `Intent`, the activity will be started in a new task, and not within the caller's task.

This isn't called a "child app", so I have rephrased your question to use the correct words.

Comment: Thanks David, it works now as expected.

Next challenge is to read a new intent, when the player app is already running. With onResume I get only the old data from the first activity start.

Comment: Implement `onNewIntent()`. This is called with the new `Intent` before `onResume()` is called.

Comment: Yes, I found this meanwhile, seems to work also. I see you're from Frankfurt. Me too ;) So, after searching days and finally signing up on StackOverflow to find a solution, it comes directly from the neigbourhood.